# add button in action bar. Not menu, only buttom

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I have a menu in my application but now I want add a button with icon "+". So in menu I will have "+" button and menu.

My code is this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing, you will have to override onOptionItemSelected() method in your actvity. if you only want to add a button You could do it this way

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/example"
    android:icon="@drawable/example"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example, menu);
    return true;
}
```

By doing this you could add the + button. Now if you want set a onClickListner you will have override this code

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       //YOUR CODE HERE
    return true;
}
```

So if you want to add a button you do it this way. ThankYou